# Energy estimates and solutions to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, differential

I have a general question about the use of energy estimates to prove existence theorems for certain PDEs:

Let some energy be defined, for example as

$$E(t)= \dfrac{1}{2} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} u^T A u \ dx $$

for a function $u:[t_0, \infty ) \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ some matrix.

Then often, the idea of proof is to show existence for $E$ and local existence of $u$ around some $t \in [t_0, \infty )$ and that's it. For me, it seems like it should be obvious how to get the existence of an $u$ from this.

Is it obvious or do they just often omit this part of proof in the books I'm working through?

Comment: In many cases I have seen, energy estimates are used to prove a global existence result, assuming one already has a local existence result (and thus that $E$ is defined for some $t$).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I've edited my question! Yes, I also noticed that there are local existence results but I still don't see how I can follow golbal existence from local existence and from existence of the energy

Comment: It's not the existence of the energy that is important in proofs of global existence, but a bound on the energy. For instance, there is generally a blowup criterion (say, either the solution can be extended for more time, or the energy blows up at an endpoint). Thus, one proves that the energy is uniformly bounded, allowing you to extend the interval of existence.

Comment: So proving existence of the energy everywhere is not enough`?

Comment: Well, you're right that if the energy exists the solution must exist to define it. What is (usually? sometimes? Idk, I'm not an expert in the field) done is that local existence gives you a solution $u : [0, T) \to \mathbb{R}$. Thus also $E : [0, T) \to \mathbb{R}$. In some cases if we can show that $\lim_{t \to T} E(t) < \infty$, we can prove that $u$ can be extended a bit to a solution $u : [0, T + \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$. In some cases one can iterate and conclude global existence.